# set background image for entire iPhone / iPad app

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad

I have a single image I want as the background for my app no matter what viewcontroller they are on - how do you accomplish this?

Answer (score 91, accepted):

Here's how you set a background to an image:

```
self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Background.png"]];
```

---

**Edit:** To write up what Felixyz said (and thanks to Manni), do this in your delegate:

```
window.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Background.png"]];
```

**And in each view you want to have the image, do this:**

```
self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

Comment: I ended up using an UIImageView on the main window nib and UIColor clearColor on my views.  Note that using the colorWithPatternImage as you state above made my memory use jump from 1.7M to 9.5M when the app is first loaded - colorWithPatternImage seems to just eat up a ton of memory.

Comment: It's recommended to prepare 3 png files for your Universal app, says Background.png, Background@2x.png, Background~iPad.png, and set the background using below code:

self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Background"]];

iOS will select the correct png file due to your device category.
Hope this help.

Comment: I tried the above approach in a `UINavigation` based application .the problem with with this approach is that setting a image on the window.background set the image properly but making the other view clear color is bad as during push or pop view are overlapping you can see the views pushed in the stack .Any idea how to get it fixed

Comment: I solved the problem from Aiden by setting the background color, as suggested in this answer, to the navigation controller view background. Then, as I'm using Storyboards, I'm replacing the standard push animation (with sliding views) with a custom UIStoryboardSegue that implements a fading effect: the image remains stable and the effect lamented by Aiden is no longer visible. In my case I'm not using navigation bars too, they are all hidden (with the exception of modal views).

Comment: @viggio24 how to create "custom UIStoryboardSegue that implements a fading effect" exactly?

Comment: @Arefly There are plenty of tutorials on how to do this. One of them is: http://blog.jimjh.com/a-short-tutorial-on-custom-storyboard-segues.html where you will replace the flipping animation with an animation on opacity (alpha).

Answer (score 8):

Depends on what sort of interface you have. Tabbed? Navigation based? But the general answer is: add a UIImageView to your UIWindow before/below your main view. Then make every view handled by your main view controller have a transparent background. Hard to give more specific advice without knowing if you use IB or not, or what your view hierarchy looks like.

Comment: Navigation based, so as view controllers are pushed and popped the background stays

Comment: Combining sudo's and Manni's suggestions makes it easy to accomplish what you need: set the backgroundColor on the window to be an image (colorWithPatternImage:) and make backgroundColor on the navigation controller and all its sub-controllers transparent. You might have to set opaque = NO on them too. Be aware that this might affect performance during animations, but shouldn't be a problem on newer devices.

Answer (score 8):

In my app, I set a default background color. Maybe you can do this with you background image:

1.: Set the background color of your UIWindow in your AppDelegate:

```
window.backgroundColor = [UIColor myBackgroundGray]; // own Category
```

2.: And now, make all other views transparent:

```
self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor]; // = transparent
```

Comment: This causes a poor ux when presenting modal presenters with animation. You can see the controls from the modal view and the existing view and then the existing view disappears.

Answer (score 7):

In your AppDelegate in

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
```

Add this line :

```
[self.window setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"background.png"]]];
```

After you just have to set your views backgrounds to `[UIColor clearColor];`

Answer (score 2):

Your background is a property of any View-inheriting object. Labels, Buttons, Controllers, and the app window, for example, all have backgrounds.  If you want it to be completely a bg for the entire app you must climb the path in your controllers to find the very "top" (bottom-viewed) view, and set its background to be the image you desire.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure of the performance implications, but I needed to accomplish something similar, and ended up using a UIImageView which works well (in C#, but works the same in obj-c):

```
//Add the view controller first, to ensure proper order of views later.
Window.RootViewController = new UIViewController();

//create backdrop image view
var imageView = new UIImageView(Window.Bounds);
imageView.Image = UIImage.FromBundle("backdrop.jpg");

//insert into window.
Window.InsertSubview(imageView, 0);
```

This doesn't handle orientation changes, but in my case, allowed me to add motion effects to the backdrop (such as parallax).

Answer (score 2):

just call this `assignbackground` in `viewDidLoad`

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
assignbackground()
}

func assignbackground(){
        let background = UIImage(named: "background")

        var imageview : UIImageView!
        imageview = UIImageView(frame: view.bounds)
        imageview.contentMode =  UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFill
        imageview.clipsToBounds = true
        imageview.image = background
        imageview.center = view.center
        view.addSubview(imageview)
        self.view.sendSubviewToBack(imageview)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I usually use this function to avoid overlaps with navigation bar on iphone.

```
-(void)setImageBackground:(NSString*)imageName{
    UINavigationController* navigationController = [self navigationController];
    float height = navigationController.toolbar.frame.size.height;
    CGSize size = self.view.frame.size;
    size.height = size.height;
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(size);
    CGRect bounds = self.view.bounds;
    bounds.origin.y = bounds.origin.y + height;
    bounds.size.height = bounds.size.height-height;
    [[UIImage imageNamed:imageName] drawInRect:bounds];
    UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:image];
}
```