# How do I get my ViewController background to show up in a half-curl transition?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, animation

I'm creating an app that uses the "i" button to show an instructions page via the half curl modal transition to another view in my storyboard. I recently used the code in this answer to set a persistent background image when you tap either of the two icons to jump to a soundboard view: [set background image for entire iPhone / iPad app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4915474/set-background-image-for-entire-iphone-ipad-app)

The problem is, the half curl doesn't seem to pick up on the background image and the page turns transparent when it curls. What would I have needed to do to ahve the background image be part of the transition? This works fine when I had a basic black color background. I have before and after transition pics below.

[Before transition](http://db.tt/zUxUTUD3)

[After Transition](http://db.tt/qemvHphS)

Comment: How exactly are you doing this curl?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the page curl effect is applied to the view, if you followed the code in the other answer, your view has no background image and its background color is clear. You'll probably need to apply the window's background image to your view just before the page curl happens.

Comment: Actually i figured out a workaround by using an ImageView pushed to the back layer of the view to create a background image rather than set an image to the background of the view itself.