# Set Absolute Background for Entire App

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uiviewcontroller

I would like to place an absolute background image for my app that does not move no matter what.

I would like it to seem as though my segues simply move the `destinationViewController`'s views onto this background, as if it were one page.

I have seen this answer, [set background image for entire iPhone / iPad app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4915474/set-background-image-for-entire-iphone-ipad-app), but as stated, `colorWithPatternImage` devours memory.

I would like an answer in Objective-C and Swift please.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way is to add a `UIImageView` to your root window and make sure all of your other views have transparent backgrounds;

```
 func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    let window=self.window!

    let backgroundView=UIImageView(frame: window.frame)

    backgroundView.image=UIImage(named: "Background.JPG")!

    window.addSubview(backgroundView)

    return true
}
```

or in Objective-C

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
// Override point for customization after application launch.

    UIWindow *window=application.windows.firstObject;
    UIImageView *imageView=[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:window.frame];

    imageView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"Background.jpg"];

    [window addSubview:imageView];
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: I believe this smokes my memory as well but I'll accept it

Comment: @EricJohnson in other options you can create a baseViewController with background and inherit all viewcontroller with transperant color from that baseViewController

Comment: That will result in a consistent background, but as each view controller has its own background image, the image will still move during view controller transitions.

Comment: @EricJohnson Memory use will depend on your image. For example for my test app, base memory usage is about 22MB.  With a  6.8MB high-res JPEG, this rise to about 90MB - Whether the image is in the window or a UIImageView on the actual VC.  With a 800Kb image, usage is about 24MB.  Since the image has to be uncompressed and rendered as a full bitmap, larger images will use more memory, regardless of how they are shown